# Angular 5 cli not working after being installed globally

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am using `Node 8.9.3` and `npm 5.5.1` and I have installed Angular latest version with this command:

`npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

Then, I set the path in the environment variable as

```
PATH C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin
```

Finally I run

`ng --version`

which results the following error:

> 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

Please help me in fixing this error.

Comment: WHy would you change your path ? I've never had have to do that ...

Comment: @trichetriche it is a suggestion given by somebody. without doing that also same issue happens.

Comment: Probably not given by the Angular team though.

Comment: @trichetriche  have followed everything given in angular docs. Having the latest version of node and npm. Still the same.

Comment: I just checked (to be sure), I have no reference to the CLI in my path. Remove it and see how it goes.

Comment: You set your windows path to _only_ the angular cli bin folder? Don't do that. Undo that change and tell us what happens.

Comment: I do have a npm reference in my path though. Maybe you should put a NPM reference back ?

Comment: Check if you have npm path working also? do `npm -v`

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time. It works well with Node.js command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `%AppData%\npm;` to the user `PATH` variable to fix it. (`%AppData%` maps to the appropriate dir for the user)

You will need to log out, and then log back in for the change to your `PATH` variable to take effect.

You can get help from [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1183).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time. It works well with Node.js command prompt.

Comment: I saw same on github and its fixed now and working fine